# Calculate minimum angle to rotate arrow to token

Tags: javascript, math, game-development

I am developing a platform game, and I would like there to be an arrow pointing to a token:

[image]

Just snapping the arrow to the token is fine - everything works correctly:

```
const dist_x = player.x - token.x
const dist_y = player.y - token.y
const angle = Math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x)

arrow.angle = angle
```

But the problem is that I would like the arrow to swing around the token as shown below. It works OK, but when the angle of the arrow is near 360 and the angle of the token is near 0, the code thinks that the arrow needs to swing all the way around to zero - as opposed to just adding up a bit and nicely looping around. This is my code:

```
const dist_x = player.x - token.x
const dist_y = player.y - token.y
const angle = Math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x) // angle between arrow & token

arrow.angle += arrow.rot_speed // acceleration
arrow.rot_speed *= .9 // slowly calm down

// distance between goal angle of arrow and angle at the moment
const angle_dist = angle - arrow.angle

// move in that direction
arrow.rot_speed += angle_dist
```

This problem has been a large stopping blocker for me on multiple occasions so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should be working with radians, not degrees as JavaScript works with radians. If you really must insist on using degrees, add some helper functions to convert radians to degrees and vice versa.

Comment: I do use radians in my javascript code, it's just I find it easier to talk about angles in degrees. But anyway, thats not the problem.

Comment: Do you have some demo already where we can jump right in and start debugging? Maybe something like https://jsfiddle.net or https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix something like this, you'd need to check if the difference of the angle you're swinging to is below 180, and if it's not, add 360 to the angle you're swinging to. I think that would fix the part where it would swing around. I don't know how you'd implement this in your code, but this is the general solution I came across on previous experiences.

Ofcourse, you'd need to convert all of this into radians :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this helps. Suppose that there are values of `dist_x` and `dist_y` used to get the angle back using `atan2()` as follow

```js
N = 8
r = 1
console.log("angle dist_x dist_y atan2 angle")
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  {
  q = (i / 8) * 2 * Math.PI
  dist_x = r * Math.cos(q)
  dist_y = r * Math.sin(q)
  theta = Math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x)
  theta2 = theta
  if(q > Math.PI) {
    theta2 += 2 * Math.PI
  }
  console.log(
    q.toFixed(3),
    dist_x.toFixed(3),
    dist_y.toFixed(3),
    theta.toFixed(3),
    theta2.toFixed(3)
  )
}
```

that produces

```
angle   dist_x  dist_y  atan2  angle
0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000  0.000
0.785   0.707   0.707   0.785  0.785
1.571   0.000   1.000   1.571  1.571
2.356  -0.707   0.707   2.356  2.356
3.142  -1.000   0.000   3.142  3.142
3.927  -0.707  -0.707  -2.356  3.927   <---
4.712  -0.000  -1.000  -1.571  4.712   <---
5.498   0.707  -0.707  -0.785  5.498   <---
```

which is showing that results in 3rd and 4th quadrants

> 3rd quadrant: `dist_x < 0`, `dist_y < 0` 
> 4rd quadrant: `dist_x > 0`, `dist_y < 0`

must be added with 2 PI to get all angle between 0 and 2 PI.

**Edit** 
Possible implementation to the given code

```js
..
const angle = Math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x) // angle between arrow & token

/* 
result of atan2():
dist_x > 0, dist_y > 0 ==>    0  < angle <  PI/2  (1st quadrant)
dist_x < 0, dist_y > 0 ==>  PI/2 < angle <  PI    (2nd quadrant)
dist_x < 0, dist_y < 0 ==> -PI   < angle < -PI/2  (3rd quadrant)
dist_x > 0, dist_y < 0 ==> -PI/2 < angle <  0     (4th quadrant)
*/

// Map all angles from (-PI, PI) to (0, 2 PI)
if(dist_y < 0) angle += 2 * Math.PI
```

Comment: I don't really understand. What is **q**, **r** or **i** meant to be? You could try renaming some variables or inserting a few explanatory comments to make it clearer. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I try to simulate some values of `dist_x` and `dist_y` by generating those. Basically, there are four quadrants where sign of `dist_x` and `dist_y` will be different: I (x>0, y>0), II (x<0, y>0), III (x<0,y<0), and IV (x>0, y<0). In the last two quadrants, i.e. III and IV, the result of `atan2()` will be negative. I assume that could be the source of your problem.

`q` is angle, `r` is radius, `i` is number from 0 to 7, since I simulate 8 points in reproducing `dist_x` and `dist_y` for representing the four quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Aquil Contractor for your answer, I had a play around with the code and this is the solution I came up with:

```
const dist_x = player.x - token.x
const dist_y = player.y - token.y

let angle = Math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x) // angle between arrow & token

const quarter = Math.PI / 2 // equivalent to 90° (I just thought I'd mention)

/* if the distance between the angles is greater
than 180°, bring the goal angle toward the current. */
if (arrow.angle > quarter && angle < -quarter) angle += Math.PI * 2
else if (arrow.angle < -quarter && angle > quarter) angle -= Math.PI * 2

arrow.angle += arrow.rot_speed
arrow.rot_speed *= .9
arrow.rot_speed += angle - arrow.angle
```

The solution was a lot simpler than I expected, but it works well and it makes sense.

Thanks all for your help and ideas!